# How do you change a master view controller from UITableViewController to UIViewController in a storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard, uisplitviewcontroller

I was wondering if it is possible to change the master view controller in a split view controller from UITableView to UIViewController in a storyboard. I am looking for a way to make the master view contain regular non scrolling controls on the top and left sides with a scrollable table view talking up the rest of the view space.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the table view controller (and the navigation controller if you want), drag out a UIView controller, and hook it up (control drag) either to the split view controller or the navigation controller, if you're using that.